# How to check if a given expression is a valid math expression?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an android calculator in android studio using java. All the functions works good. But I don't want buttonEQL to work if the string is not containing a valid math expression (i.e it should not contain other characters and not like 2*3/+4).

```
buttonEQL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (result.getText().length()>0){

                String expression = result.getText().toString();
                Double res= new DoubleEvaluator().evaluate(expression);
                result.setText(res.toString());

            }
            else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"no no no ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
    });
```

I'm a beginner!

Comment: Looked at ```Dijkstra's stack algo``` ? https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Evaluate.java.html

Comment: The [Javaluator](http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/) library doesn't support *validating* the expression without *executing* it. If you need that kind of functionality, you should find a different library.

Comment: Whats the other one? @Andreas

Comment: What "other one"? There are many expression libraries out there, you just have to **do your own research** to find them, and then decide which one best matches your need. Don't ask here, because [questions asking us to recommend or find a software library is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).